# How to find the control present in an iframe using selenium?

Tags: selenium

I want to find the control present in an iFrame in a webpage using selenium to perform actions like click and setting text in textbox. What is the best way to do that using c# or java language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using below code you get controls inside iframe in chrome driver. Install latest selenium chromedriver and place it at C:\chromedriver.exe to below code

```
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
            
            // Initialize browser
            WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            
            //navigate to url
            driver.get("https://demoqa.com/frames");
            
            //Switch to Frame using Index
            driver.switchTo().frame(0);
            
            //Identifying the heading in webelement
            WebElement frame1Heading= driver.findElement(By.id("sampleHeading"));
            
            //Finding the text of the heading
            String frame1Text=frame1Heading.getText();
            
            //Print the heading text
            System.out.println(frame1Text);
            
            //closing the driver
            driver.close();
```